# Executed PHP Script Cannot Access GCS Mounted Drive on GCE

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

I was able to mount my Google Cloud Storage using the command line below:

`gcsfuse -o allow_other -file-mode=660 -dir-mode=770  --uid=<uid> --gid=<gid> testbucket /path/to/domain/folder`

The group includes the user **apache**. Apache is able to write to the mounted drive like so:

`sudo -u apache echo 'Some Test Text' > /path/to/domain/folder/hello.txt`

**hello.txt** appears in the bucket as expected. However when I execute the below php script I get an error:

`<?php file_put_contents('/path/to/domain/folder/hello.txt', 'Some Test Text');`

PHP Error: **failed to open stream: Permission denied**

`echo exec('whoami');` Returns **apache**

I assumed this is a common use for mounting with gcsfuse or something similar to this but, I seem to be the only one on the internet with this issue. I do not know if its an issue with the way I mounted it or the service security of httpd.

Comment: There are a lot of moving parts here. Are you able to reproduce the problem without PHP or even Apache? That would help a lot. Failing that, maybe you could use `strace` to see exactly what system call(s) PHP is making that fail.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue.

Use the flag `--implicit-dirs` while mounting the Google Storage bucket using gcsfuse. More on this [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md#implicit-directories).

Mounting the bucket as a folder makes the OS to treat it like a regular folder which may contain files and folders. But Google Cloud Storage bucket doesn't have directory structures. For example, when you are creating a file named `hello.txt` in a folder named `files` inside a Google Storage bucket, you are not actually creating a folder and putting the file in it. The object is created in the bucket with the name as `files/hello.txt`. More on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/key-terms#object-names) and [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/semantics.md#files-and-directories).

To make the OS treat the GCS bucket like a hierarchical structure, you have to specify the `--implicit-dirs` flag to the gcsfuse.

**Note:**
I wouldn't recommend using gcsfuse in production systems as it is a beta quality software.

Comment: I do see the difference in behavior with the folders but, unfortunately that didn't fix the issue for me. I am still not able to save files with PHP. I will be using the API instead. Thanks for your help!